# Checking if a peer is still connected to a non-blocking socket with WinSock 2.x

Tags: c, networking, winsock

I'm looking for a way to verify if a peer is still connected to a TCP non-blocking socket (server), I have this code:

```
Is_Client_Connected(SOCKET *s)
{

    struct sockaddr name;
    INT32 name_len = sizeof(name), retval;
    retval = getpeername(*s, &name, &name_len);
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == WSAENOTCONN)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

But for some reason, when I use this and the client is disconnected from the server, getpeername() returns no socket error - instead it return 0 (Success).

I realize this getpeername() might not be the function I am looking for, but I looked at the WinSock reference and I couldn't find anything to suit my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is baseless. *This socket* is still open and connected, so why should `getpeername()` fail? Where is the behaviour you're expecting described?

The *correct* way to detect a clean peer disconnect is to try to read from the socket. If `recv()` returns zero, the peer has closed the connection. A positive result indicates data pending; a result of SOCKET_ERROR indicates an error of some kind, not necessarily indicating a connection failure. You can use the MSG_PEEK flag to prevent actually consuming any pending data.

Comment: Hi, I accidently downvoted but this is indeed the right way to do it (combined with another conditional value to check if the connection was not gracefully ended)

If you'd edit the answer I could upvote it back (Upvoting is locked)